# Load denied by X-Frame-Options allow in Firefox

Tags: firefox, x-frame-options

how to allow in firefox viewing content site secure by X-Frame-Options like www.google.com

i add in (about:config) settings

```
browser.frames.enabled = true
```

and its worked for some time but now it's not working again

Answer (score 3):

I find good solution not for firefox but for chrome:

plugin: Ignore X-Frame headers

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ignore-x-frame-headers/gleekbfjekiniecknbkamfmkohkpodhe?hl=en-US

Answer (score 1):

I've created an add-in for Firefox which ignores all x-frame options, see https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ignore-x-frame-options/

Btw, this this question is similar to [Disable X-Frame-Option on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881789/disable-x-frame-option-on-client-side/31391703)