# How do I redirect to a URL after submitting an HTML form built with Google Scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect, google-apps-script

I created a form which uploads form field data to a Google Sheet and uploads a file to Google Drive. Right now, upon submission, the page is redirected to a new page that says "File uploaded successfully to the google drive url."

I want to redirect to a specific URL. How do I do this?

!!UPDATE 7/20!! I have updated the code as recommended by Jonas W below. However, after checking the debugger, the following error is issued:

"Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fn-a5ewhrjyamnkpqisqxvdofomdabpix44dfr7wvq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com%2Fcenterforalternativefuels.org&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fn-a5ewhrjyamnkpqisqxvdofomdabpix44dfr7wvq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com%2Fcenterforalternativefuels.org does not permit framing."

Any recommendations as to how to work around X-Frame-Options?

Here is the current redirect code at the end of my file upload function:

```
return "File uploaded successfully" + file.getUrl();
```

The file upload function is called in the form html file:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" 
   onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
            .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
            return false;" style="margin-top: 20px">
```

And here is the fileUploaded code from the form html file:

```
<script>
 function fileUploaded(status){ 
  window.location="http://centerforalternativefuels.org";
 }
</script>
```

Comment: The [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) is a Http response header that can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>` or `<object>` . Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites. So if you have a problem with this, I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370978/load-denied-by-x-frame-options-allow-in-firefox) can help you. You can try to use the extension here to ignore the X-frame header

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function fileUploaded(status){ 
window.location="http://newurl";
}
</script>
```

Comment: where do i call this function?

Comment: You have to replace newurl with the url you want to. I think this is understandable

Comment: Yes, I knew that. I tried to redirect to my desired URL and it didn't work.

Comment: There are no errors when the form is submitted. The data is uploaded to a google sheet and the file is uploaded to google drive. How else can I check for errors or things that could be debugged?

Comment: Using firefox do right click and then debug. The developer window will open and you can check if anything was logged.

Comment: Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fn-a5ewhrjyamnkpqisqxvdofomdabpix44dfr7wvq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com%2Fcenterforalternativefuels.org&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fn-a5ewhrjyamnkpqisqxvdofomdabpix44dfr7wvq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com%2Fcenterforalternativefuels.org does not permit framing.