# How to add a floating button in ionic2 InAppBrowser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am loading an external URL in ionic2 **InAppBrowser**. I want to add a floating  button above the webview for capturing the screenshot of the webpage which is loaded in the InAppBrowser. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with doing that with **InAppBrowser** is that it sets itself as top z-index so no matter what you add it will be under it.

Here is a workaround using `iframe` and `FabButtons`(or `Floating Action Buttons`:  [fab docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/fab/FabButton/))

[image]

For example:

**.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <iframe no-margin name="myName" [src]=cleanUrl></iframe>
</ion-content>
<ion-fab left top>
  <button ion-fab color="danger" (click)="buttonClick()">
    <ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-fab>
```

**.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: '<SELECTOR HERE>',
  templateUrl: '<PAGE NAME HERE>.html',
})
export class MyPage {

  url: string;
  cleanUrl: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer   
  ) {
    this.url = 'http://www.example.com/';
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.cleanUrl = this.sanatizeUrl(this.url);
  }

  sanatizeUrl(url: string): any{
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }

  buttonClick() {
    console.log('buttonClick');
  }
}
```

Please note the use of [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) that will be necessary if you get errors displaying the url.

Comment: how to place this fab button in **InAppBrowser** ?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible with `InAppBrowser`, but here is a workaround using `iframe`

Comment: Thanks for your response. i am trying to open a https site and getting the error  "Load denied by X-Frame-Options:".

Comment: Some websites have a server setting that will not allow other websites to "frame" their content. This is mainly to protect their copyrights and direct traffic to their websites only - Unfortunately, there is really nothing you can do about it if you want to frame the website.

For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699221/load-denied-by-x-frame-options-does-not-permit-framing