# Iframe not working in browser?

Tags: html, iframe

I try **iframe** its working fine in chrome but not working on **Mozila and IE.**

```html
<iframe id="iframe1" src="https://stackoverflow.com/" width="200" height="100" border="2"></iframe>
```

Comment: Actually it is working fine. Checked in Mozilla

Comment: @Sankar not working i checked on mozila console the error shown"Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://stackoverflow.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing."

Comment: My bad, I checked it in stack snippets. Some websites does not allow other website to frame their content. So they restricted that access from web server. You can't do anything with this.

Comment: @Sankar if i add another site it will not open. can you have solution plz.

Comment: No you can't override this. You can see the same behaviour in Google, Yahoo... etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load denied by X-Frame-Options: does not permit framing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699221/load-denied-by-x-frame-options-does-not-permit-framing)

Comment: @Sankar any alternative solutions?