# Always getting Load denied by X-Frame-Options, already set in express.js using helmet

Tags: node.js, express, x-frame-options

I am getting same error again and again. I have used helmet for X-Frame-Options and for other headers use access-allow. In firefox Console shows "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: does not permit framing." In chrome console shows "Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."
Please give me some solution. Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
var app = express();
var helmet = require('helmet');
app.use(helmet({
  frameguard: {
    action: 'allow-from',
    domain: 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/'
  }
}))

var enableCORS = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, token, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, *');
  if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
app.all("/*", function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, token, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, *');
  // res.set('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM htps://google.com/');
  next();
});
app.use(enableCORS);
```

Comment: Your config there basically enables `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/` to put your pages in `iframe`, is that what you want to do ?

Comment: Yes. I want to open google calendar in iframe..

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration does the opposite :

```
  frameguard: {
               action: 'allow-from',
               domain: 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/'
              }
```

will allow https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ to put **your** page in an iframe.
Some websites will not allow other websites to frame their content, and that's why you got the error, because if https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ sets `X-Frame-Options` to `DENY` , `SAMEORIGIN` or `ALLOW-FROM http://example.com` where http://example.com is some other domain **different** from yours, you can't frame any of https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ content.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699221/load-denied-by-x-frame-options-does-not-permit-framing) and [here](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/frameguard/) for more informations.

Comment: Yes.. X-Frame-Options is not allowing me to render the contents from google calendar. But requirement is to load google calendar in iframe!! Is there any way to allow??

Comment: X-Frame-Options will not enable you to load google calendar in an iframe, you can't do that unfortunately since you don't have any control over their config.

Comment: So is this a required evil to have on a site if you need Google Calendar?